# RPG/RPGLE - behavior of data structure containing signed and packed values:

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

... updating some old code and ran into interesting behavior of data structure containing signed and packed values:

```
D  #SIGNED        S              5S 0 INZ                           
D  #PACKED        S              5P 0 INZ                           
D*---                                                               
D #AS_1           DS                                                
D  #AS1                               LIKE(#SIGNED) INZ             
D  #AS2                               LIKE(#SIGNED) INZ             
D  #AS3                               LIKE(#SIGNED) INZ             
D #AP_1           DS                                                
D  #AP1                               LIKE(#PACKED) INZ             
D  #AP2                               LIKE(#PACKED) INZ             
D  #AP3                               LIKE(#PACKED) INZ             
C                                                                   
C*  for single signed, this is true                       
C     #AS1          IFEQ      *ZEROS                      
C                   EXSR      MYSR                        
C                   ENDIF                                 
C                                                         
C*  for single packed, this is true                       
C     #AP1          IFEQ      *ZEROS                      
C                   EXSR      MYSR                        
C                   ENDIF                                 

C*  for DS of signed, this is true                        
C     #AS_1         IFEQ      *ZEROS                      
C                   EXSR      MYSR                        
C                   ENDIF                                 
C                                                         
C*  however for DS of packed, this is false                            
C     #AP_1         IFEQ      *ZEROS                                   
C                   EXSR      MYSR                                     
C                   ENDIF                                              
C                                                                      
C                   Eval       *INLR = *ON                             
C                   Return                                             
 *****************************************************************     
C     MYSR          BEGSR                                              
C                   ENDSR
```

I assume this is because of how packed is stored internally...

Comment: Please don't pummel me for not using /free.  I am just fixing old code.

Answer (score 4):

It's a combination of things...

A DS is just a collection of BYTES, since RPG doesn't have a BYTE type, it basically treats it as a collection SBCS characters.

*ZEROS is a Symbolic name that translate to a repeating x'F0' for the length of the compared/assigned to variable.

The character '0' is x'F0', the zoned decimal digit 0 is also 'F0'

A single-digit packed 0 is x'0F'

However,
zoned(5,0)  is x'F0F0F0F0F0'
packed(5,0) is x'00000F'

So AS_1 is treated as char(15) x'F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0'
AP_1 is treated as char(9) x'00000F00000F00000F'

So it is easy to see that AS_1 == *ZEROS but AP_1 <> *ZEROS

Comment: The character '0' and the zoned decimal digit are x'F0', not x'0F'.

Comment: A single digit packed 0 is x'0F' not x'F0'.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy...picky aren't you? It was right till I replaced all the 0F with F0 .... :p